# Java Jackson parsing a error with improper json string

Tags: java, json, parsing, jackson

I am trying to parse the following error from FeignException as a Json

```
status 412 reading SampleClient#updateUuid(Long,UpdateRequest); content:\n{\"timestamp\":\"2017-06-20T10:46:54.306+0000\",\"status\":412,\"message\":\"Invalid Id\",\"path\":\"/client/12344/updateUuid\",\"error\":true}",
```

But getting the following error

> ERROR
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/].[dispatcherServlet]
>   Servlet.service() for servlet dispatcherServlet threw exception
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token
>   'status': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')  at [Source:
>   status 412 reading SampleClient#updateUuid(Long,UpdateRequest); 
>   content:
>   {"timestamp":"2017-06-20T10:55:14.380+0000","status":412,"message":"Invalid
>   Id","path":"/client/12344/updateUuid","error":true}; line: 1, column:
>   7]

I am looking to actually get the "message":"Invalid Id" node.

Can someone kindly help.

Thanks in advance for you time.

Comment: You should post your java code  that's reading the json and whatever class your trying  to convert the json into

Comment: It seems that the class Jackson wants to generate has a property status that is not a integer.

Answer (score 0):

You are not sending the parser well formed json. You are sending

```
status 412 reading SampleClient#updateUuid(Long,UpdateRequest); content:\n{\"timestamp\":\"2017-06-20T10:46:54.306+0000\",\"status\":412,\"message\":\"Invalid Id\",\"path\":\"/client/12344/updateUuid\",\"error\":true}",
```

when you should be sending

```
{"timestamp":"2017-06-20T10:46:54.306+0000","status":412,"message":"Invalid Id","path":"/client/12344/updateUuid","error":true}"
```

Trim the first line (\n being the line delimiter) and last comma and it should parse, but I have to wonder why you would be doing this in the first place. Please post your code so that we can better comment on your use case.